# multiple mysqli delete codes on one PHP page

Tags: php, mysqli

I am still learing PHP and MySQLI and was wondering if it is possible to host multiple MySQLI delete queries on a single php page and have the url act on the corresponding query without confusion. I have this code here, I have search the web for an answer for 3 days but nothing I found seemed to be what I was looking for. Any help or properly described examples based on my code would be greatly appreciated.

my Code is:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include ('dbconnect.php');
$userr = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
$uid=$_GET['pid'];
$pid=$_GET['phid'];
$user_id=$_GET['user'];
$fileID=$_GET['file'];
if($userr==$uid && $pid==$fileID){
    echo "ERROR No. 9B2AP";
    }else{
    mysqli_query($con,"delete from images where userID='$uid' AND PhotoID='$pid'") or die (mysqli_error());
    header ("location: /viewImage.php?pid=$uid");
}

if($userr==$user_id && $fileID==$pid){
    echo "ERROR No. 39V41";
    }else{
    mysqli_query($con,"delete from music where userID='$user_id' AND Record_ID='$fileID'") or die (mysqli_error());
    header ("location: /users/music-gallery/$user_id");
}
?>
```

No matter how many times I rewrite this code, when i delete an image or song using the code on this page, It redirects me only to the `/users/music-gallery/` instead of the proper associated page. How might I get this fixed? Like I said, I am fairy new to PHP and MySQLI and any suggestions I believe should be described in details so I might be able to understand and comprehend how I made the mistake and I to fix and prevent it from happening again in later code. Please and Thank-you.
-M.S

Comment: `$_GET['file']` that suggests file handling, which requires a POST method and a valid enctype. Check for errors with error reporting and the query. `mysqli_error()` requires a db connection as the argument.

Comment: you're also open to a serious sql injection here, did you know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons don't do this:

```
// Consider escaping the incoming data for better security
$uid=$_GET['pid'];
$pid=$_GET['phid'];
// ...
```

Since you are using `MySQLi` you can use this to escape your data:

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['pid']);
```

You can use `FILTERS` to check input data type:

```
// If you are expecting an `INT` from $_GET['pid']
if (filter_var($_GET['pid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
{
    echo 'pid is an int';
}
else
{
    echo 'pid is not an int';
}
```

more on filters [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

The best of all, use `prepared mysqli statements` with `stmt`:

```
// prepare the statement
$stmt = $con->prepare("delete from images where userID=? AND PhotoID=?");
// bind variables to the '?' and set types --> `i` = integer
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $_GET['pid'], $_GET['phid']);
// execute query
$stmt->execute();

// Do the same for the next query
```

more on prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

**To solve your problem:**

To `exit` a program right after a header you need to use `exit();` after each `header` like this:

```
header ("location: /viewImage.php?pid=$uid");
exit();
```

For instance:

```
header ("location: /viewImage.php?pid=$uid");
// this line of code gets exucuted
// this too
// ...

header ("location: /viewImage.php?pid=$uid");
exit();
// Nothing gets executed as program terminates and redirects
```

Comment: it's suggested but I doubt that is the problem here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner turns out he just had an `exit` problem, I edited to show his security flaws as well

Comment: Cool. I myself used to use real_escape_string() till I learned about prepared statements ;-) they're a lot safer, *just saying*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner same here, but introducing examples of prepared statements seemed too much here, eventhough I mentioned it :)

Comment: you could have included a reference link from the php.net website and pulling an example from it. That's what I do sometimes and others as well ;-)

Comment: Just a quick sidenote: About `$_GET['xxx'];` and the additional functions. Doing `(int)$_GET['int']` is good enough to help prevent injection. Strings however as compared to integers, require the values being prepared. Edit: You're welcome; just saw your note as I was typing this.